# custom messages displayed in amchart pdf downloaded file

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am using amchart version 3.16.I need custom messages to be displayed in amchart downloaded pdf image instead of showing 'Saved from:url'.
How can I have custom messages in downloaded file ?
The code is something like this.

```
"menu": [ {
                        "label": "Download",
                        "menu": [
                            { "label": "PNG",
                                click: function() {
                                    this.capture({},function() {
                                        this.toPNG( {}, function( data ) {
                                            this.download( data, "image/png", fileName+'.png');
                                        });
                                    });}},

                            { "label": "JPG",
                                click: function() {
                                    this.capture({},function() {
                                        this.toJPG( {}, function( data ) {
                                            this.download( data, "image/jpg", fileName+'.jpg');
                                        });
                                    });}},

                            { "label": "SVG",
                                click: function() {
                                    this.capture({},function() {
                                        this.toSVG( {}, function( data ) {
                                            this.download( data, "text/xml", fileName+'.svg');
                                        });
                                    });}},
                            { "label": "PDF",
                                click: function() {
                                    this.capture({},function() {
                                        this.toPDF( {}, function( data ) {
                                            this.download( data, "application/pdf", fileName+'.pdf');
                                        });
                                    });}}]

                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Save as..",
                        "menu": [ { "label": "CSV"},
                            { "label": "XLSX"}
                        ]

                    },
                    {
                            "label": "Print",
                            "format":"PRINT"
                        },
                        { "label": "Annotate",
                            "action": "draw",
                            "drawing":
                            {
                                "fontSize": 30
                            }
                        }]
```

Answer (score 0):

In **export.js**, you can change the following code...

```
["Saved from:", window.location.href, {image: "reference", fit: [523.28, 769.89]}]
```

with this one:

```
[{image: "reference", fit: [523.28, 769.89]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

In export.js, you can comment/change as per your need the following code...

```
if ( cfg.pageOrigin ) {
                    pageContent.push( _this.i18l( "label.saved.from" ) );
                    pageContent.push( window.location.href );
                    pageDimensions[ 1 ] -= ( 14.064 * 2 );
                }
```

========================================================================